# Joomla 3 - Text area in Editor field breaks the Admin section

Tags: joomla-3.x, form, editor

I have an editor field with some HTML code in it. The HTML code consists of a form and one of the form fields is a text area.

When this code is added to the editor field, the Admin section of the module breaks completely. I have no idea why. This isn't caused by any other HTML form fields other than textarea.

Why is this happening and how can it be solved?

Thank you.

Comment: May I ask why you're trying to add a form to an editor field? This doesn't sound like a common practice.

Comment: @Sharky in order to allow users to modify the form code, like adding a CSS class for example.

Answer (score 1):

Editor field is actually a `<textarea>` element with editor functionality added through JavaScript. So any HTML code inside it must be escaped. Without escaping, you end up with `<textarea>` element within `<textarea>` element which is invalid HTML.

Comment: How would I go about escaping the <textarea>? Thanks.